# Can we change the contrast of questions which have at least one of our favourite tags?

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, design, bookmarks

My question is just simple and that is only common sense for me, we can choose favourite tags and I think the goal is to rise the questions we can answer, at least, and the questions which can interest us more than other in another part.

So, just to make a simple comparison, the contrast of colors between favourite tags questions vs non-favourite tags questions, is very good in [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

[image: MSE contrast favourite tags questions]

Whereas in [Chem.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/) the contrast between both is like this, almost non-existing.

[image: CSE contrast favourite tags questions]

So my question is, can we change that?

Comment: The contrast looks a little more obvious on my iMac than my MacBook, so I suspect that it depends on the quality of the screen. But generally speaking I'm with you that the design could be changed. I'm not sure how easy it is to get design changes done, but given the current incarnation has been around for a while I wonder whether there could be a larger discussion around making chem.SE look a little better/modern.

Comment: @NotCorey this is easy to change. This is just a little of CSS to change. Less than a line ;)

Comment: The whole thing would be *easy* to change, I was more thinking of whom actually has the ability to play around with the files.

Comment: @NotCorey I sent also a message at support :)

Comment: The devs usually also read the [meta-tag:feature-request] and [meta-tag:bug] questions on the child meta sites. They will probably come back to us here. The implementation should indeed be simple enough, fitting it into the existing colour scheme might need a designer to look at it. Since there are probably more sites awaiting a genuine new design (designing is the bottleneck for graduation), I would not expect this to be a priority. We will have to wait and see. Btw I have no problem with the way it looks now, but I would not mind a better contrast either.

Comment: Designer from SO here: seems like this shade of yellow is slightly lighter than shade we used to use in other places (usually, not always). I will update it with yellow used on Stack Overflow - it's slightly darker so should be more visible.

Comment: Funnily enough, I never had any difficulty recognising favourites.

Comment: @Jan you're a conjugated porphyrin, duh.

Comment: @Paweł ETA when this will be done? (the usual 6-8 days?)

Comment: Should be live with upcoming build.

Comment: @Pawel so when will it change ? ...

Comment: I guess this is no longer [meta-tag:status-planned], but instead [meta-tag:status-completed]?