# Fine-tune footer CSS

Tags: bug, design

While we are at the [fine details of CSS](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3623/24052), I'd say that sometimes there is some spacing missing above the footer.

These are screenshots from the User > Activity page.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This might be better as a [meta-tag:bug]-report on [meta.se], but not too sure. I probably affects all sites network wide.

Comment: I checked 3 sites. It is unique to Chemistry.

Comment: I think [meta-tag:bug] is more appropriate for this than [meta-tag:feature-request], and have taken the liberty to retag it as such.